# transitive closure of a set

Tags: combinatorics

I'm referring to a specific book, Lorenz Halbeisen's "Combinatorial Set Theory", with which I'm teaching myself set theory.

I understand the idea of a transitive closure, particularly with reference to sets containing pairs, constructing transitive iterations of these, etc. But I'm having difficulty understanding what motivates the construction of the proof I'm working with in this book. TC($S$) where $S$ is an arbitrary set is introduced as a result of the transfinite recursion theorem, which is itself discussed under the Axiom of Replacement. So it's discussed in the book I'm using as a result of defining a class function for all sets. What follows, through Proposition 3.10 (p. 47, for anyone who has the book on hand), I quote almost exactly, with only one clarification added in hard brackets.

Let $S$ be an arbitrary set. Define the class function $F_S$ by stipulating $F_S(x)$ := $\emptyset$ if x is not a function. Otherwise:

$F_S(x)$ = $S$ if $x$ = $\emptyset$

$F_S(x)$ = $\bigcup$$x(\beta)$ if dom($x$) = $\beta + 1$

$F_S(x)$ = $\bigcup_{\delta\in\beta}$$x(\delta)$ if dom($x$) = $\beta$ and $\beta$ is a non-empty limit ordinal

$F_S(x)$ = $\emptyset$ otherwise.

By transfinite recursion, there is a unique class function $G_S$ defined on $\Omega$ such that for each $\beta\in\Omega$ we have $G_S(\beta) = F_S(G_S|_\beta)$, [where $G_S|_\beta = \{\langle\gamma, G(\gamma)\rangle : \gamma\in\beta\}$. $-ed.$] In particular, we have $G_S(\emptyset) = S$ and for $n\in\omega$ we get $G_S(n+1) = \bigcup G_S(n).$

Proposition 3.10: The set $G_S(\omega)$ is the smallest transitive set which contains $S$, i.e., $G_S(\omega) = $TC$(S)$

So. What I get when I perform this operation is a set, in fact a sequence, of iterated unions of S. If $x = \emptyset$, then $x = G_S(\emptyset)$, which would be empty. In this way we get the result $S$ for the zero case. For $G_S(1)$ we then get $\bigcup S$; for $G_S(2)$, we get $\bigcup (\bigcup S)$ and so on. We can then call $S$ := $S_0$, $\bigcup S$ := $S_1$, $\bigcup (\bigcup S)$ := $S_2$ and so on.

What I don't understand is why this yields TC($S$). Please forgive me if I have misunderstood something here: The union of a set simply contains all sets which belong to at least one element of the set (loosely adapted quote from my book). So, if we think of a given finite set $S$ which is not transitive, like $\{0, 2\}$, then $\bigcup\{0, 2\} = \{0, 1\}$. Now $\bigcup(\bigcup\{0, 2\})$ = $\bigcup\{0, 1\}$ = $\{0, 1\}$. And so on as many times as we like, for $G_S(\omega) = \bigcup_{\delta\in\omega}$$G_S(\delta)$.

Please tell me if I am hopelessly confused. Naturally, one thing we want is TC($\omega$), since $\omega\notin\omega$. And if a set containing only ordinals is not itself an ordinal (as immediately above) we want to be able to construct the ordinal containing the entire set. We also presumably want to be able to do this in a way that doesn't require just performing ordinal addition manually on certain subsets of a given set, particularly because we ultimately want TC($\omega$). This motivates using unions to obtain transitive sets, but I am in the dark as to

a) why performing this iteration $\omega$ times ultimately makes for the transitive closure of a finite set;

b) what this has to do with $\mathscr P(\omega)$, whose construction is also, presumably, somehow behind this.

I understand that this has turned into a jeremiad, where it ought to be a concrete question. If there is one in here, it's just how I should actually *picture* the set TC($S$) for any arbitrary set $S$.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you understand that a transitive set is, by definition, a set $T$ such  that every member of a member of $T$ is also  a member of $T$. (This is, unfortunately, not the same meaning of "transitive" as in the phrase "transitive relation".)

The transitive closure of a set $S$ is intended to be the smallest transitive set TC$(S)$ that has $S$ as a subset. So TC$(S)$ must contain (as elements) first, all the elements of $S$, next all elements of elements of $S$ (required in order that TC$(S)$ be transitive), next all elements of those (again required for transitivity), and so on.

That construction of TC$(S)$ is what Halbeisen is formalizing. His $G_S(n)$ is the set of elements that you know are in $S$ after $n+1$ steps in my discussion above. $G_S(0)$ consists of the elements of $S$, i.e., $G_S(0)=S$.   Next, $G_S(1)$ consists of the elements of elements of $S$, i.e., $G_S(1)=\bigcup S=\bigcup G_S(0)$. Similarly for later stages of the discussion, $G_S(n+1)$ consists of the elements of elements of $G_S(n)$, i.e., $G_S(n+1)=\bigcup G_S(n)$.

The equations in the preceding paragraph are just the ones that Halbeisen uses for his recursive definition of $G_S$. Continuing for $\omega$ steps, we find that $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}G_S(n)$ is transitive: If it contains $x$ and if $y\in x$, then $x\in G_S(n)$ for some natural number $n$ and then $y\in G_S(n+1)$. Also, $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}G_S(n)$ has $S$ as a subset because $S=G_S(0)$. Finally, by the discussion two paragraphs ago, any transitive superset of $S$ must contain all elements of $G_S(n)$ for all $n\in\omega$, so it must contain all elements of $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}G_S(n)$.

Thus, $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}G_S(n)$ serves as TC$(S)$, the smallest transitive superset of $S$.  I hope this answers your question (a). For (b) the answer is much simpler: $\mathcal P(\omega)$ is not involved here.

Comment: Many thanks for your speedy reply. This should help me a great deal to work through the actual proof (which I didn't include in my post). And sorry if my question was unfocussed.

Comment: This also, incidentally, resolves my confusion regarding $\mathscr P(\omega)$. Halbeisen mentions in passing that this construction is a consequence of the Axiom Schema of Replacement, and that's why I thought it might be related to the transitive closure, but I see now why it's not. Thanks for that, as well!